Which Angular form type is suitable for creating a form from a Record type with string keys and object values?
I'm working on an Angular project where I need to create a form based on a data structure represented by a TypeScript Record type. The Record consists of string keys and object values, specifically, the values are of type GroupedSignals.
Here's an example of the data structure:
export interface GroupedSignals {
  groupName: string | null;
  groupId: string;
  isOpenByDefault: boolean;
  signals: MatTableDataSource<SignalModel>;
  selectionModel: SelectionModel<SignalModel>;
  selectedColumns: string[];
  isAllSignalSelected: boolean;
  expanded: boolean;
}

@inheritSerialization(WidgetConfigModel)
export class SignalListConfig extends WidgetConfigModel {
  @deserialize public signals: Record<SignalModel['Id'], GroupedSignals['groupId'] | 'ungrouped'> = {};
  @deserialize public groups: Record<GroupedSignals['groupId'], GroupedSignals> = {};

  public static override createForm() {
    return {
      ...super.createForm(),
      signals: new FormRecord<FormControl<string | 'ungrouped'>>({}, {validators: [Validators.required]}),
      groups: ???,
    };
  }
}

Now, I need to create a form using Angular's Reactive Forms module, but I'm unsure which form type (FormRecord, FormGroup, or FormControl) would be the most appropriate for this scenario.
Here are some considerations:

The keys of the Record are of type string and represent unique identifiers (groupId).
Each value in the Record is an object of type GroupedSignals, which contains various properties.
Given this data structure, should I use a FormRecord, FormGroup, or FormControl to create the form?

How can I handle the dynamic nature of the Record keys and ensure that each GroupedSignals object is represented correctly in the form?
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
